# Existence of certain real-valued continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, real-numbers

I am currently taking an undergraduate course in Real Analysis, and I am studying various continuous functions and their properties. Recently, I was thinking about the existence of some continuous functions satisfying certain properties. More explicitly, I am facing very much trouble with the following question. Please help me.

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist $f, g \in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that the following holds simultaneously?

1. $f(2) = g(2)$,
2. $f(2) \neq 0, g(2) \neq 0$,
3. $(|f| - |g|)h = 0$ for some $h \in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $h(2) \neq 0$,
4. $(f - g)h \neq 0$ for all $h \in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $h(2) \neq 0$.

My intuition says that such $f, g$ does not exist. But I am not able to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is impossible.

Conditions $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ together imply that $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $2$. Indeed, by condition $(3)$,  you can find $h$ such that $$(|f|-|g|)h=0\tag{A}$$ and since $h(2)\neq 0$ and is continuous, you know $h\neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $2$. Thus, by $(A)$, in a neighborhood of $2$, $$|f|=|g|\tag{B}$$
But since both $f$ and $g$ are non-zero at $2$ (condition $(2)$), and both are continuous, you know that each of them is of constant sign in a neighborhood of $2$. And since by $(1)$, they assume the same value at $2$, we conclude that they have the same sign in the neighborhood of $2$. So $(B)$ becomes
$f=g$ in the neighborhood of $2$.

But this contradicts $(4)$ since you can take a continuous $h$ to be 0 outside the neighborhood of $2$ where $f=g$, and $h(2)\neq 0$, and  then $$(f-g)h=0$$

Comment: I am sorry, it seems that your answer is not correct. $(f - g)h \neq 0$ means $(f - g)h$ is not a zero function. @Stefan Lafon

Comment: Yes, hence the contradiction (since we were able to prove that conditions (1), (2) and (3) imply that $(f-g)h=0$ in a neighborhood of $2$). Where do you see a problem with my answer?

Comment: The condition in $4)$ says that $(f -g)h \neq 0$, which means $(f - g)h$ is not a zero function. You showed that $(f - g)h = 0$ on some neighborhood of $2$. Does this guarantee that $(f - g)h = 0$?

Comment: Yes for a carefully chosen function $h$, such as $h$ being the indicator function of the neighborhood where $f=g$. Let me add that to my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Downvoting a post that was correct because you forgot information is not very fair to the answerer...

Comment: Thank you @BrunoB

Comment: I am sorry as I forgot to mention that here all functions are assumed to lie in $C(\mathbb{R})$. But what you wrote regarding this is not fair. I know anyone can see that the post has been edited. I have accepted your answer too. It would be nice if you could just have spoken nicely. Again, I am sorry for my mistake. Now that you know the full question, can you edit your answer? @Stefan Lafon

Comment: @Ratanjit Stefan already edited their answer. The existence of the final $h$ is slightly non-trivial but a classic "lemma" so to speak (and separate from your exercise). If you search for the keywords "compactly supported continuous function", or the same with smooth instead of continuous, you should be able to figure out why such a function exists (or you can admit its existence).

Comment: @Ratanjit I figure you might not know that you can un-downvote (or un-upvote) after an edit has been done, though of course you're never forced to. Just a heads up.